# c++ win32 hide (disable) caret from an edit box

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox, caret

I'm trying to make it so that a user can select text from a read-only edit box, but he won't see the blinking caret. I've been able to make the caret disappear from the edit, but it can still be seen for an instant.

This is my code for the subclass:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK UserInfoProc (HWND hUserInfoWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{

    HideCaret(hUserInfoWnd);

    return DefSubclassProc(hUserInfoWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}
```

It's a modest bit of code, I know, but it almost does what I want.

So what happens is, that when I click the edit, the caret can be seen for an instant (50ms?). I want that it doesn't appear at all. How can I do this? I want the user to still be able to select the text from the edit.

Comment: You could try moving the `HideCaret()` call to after the `DefSubclassProc()`, since at the moment if a message triggers the caret it won't be until the next one that it's hidden again.

Comment: Well that didn't work. How would it be possible the `HideCaret()` would ever be called if I moved it past a return statement?

Comment: You don't move it past the return statement, you save the return value from `DefSubClassProc`, call `HideCaret` and then return...

Comment: Btw, it's probably only `WM_SETFOCUS` that triggers the caret to be shown.

Comment: Yeah I got what you meant just before you commented :D and yeah! it worked! Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Can you put this as an answer so that it can accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try moving the `HideCaret()` call to after the `DefSubclassProc()`, since at the moment if a message triggers the caret it won't be until the **next** message that it's hidden again.

Also, I would guess that the only message that triggers the caret to be shown is `WM_SETFOCUS`, so you may want to test for that message only. For example,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK UserInfoProc (HWND hUserInfoWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    LRESULT lRes = DefSubclassProc(hUserInfoWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    if (uMsg == WM_SETFOCUS) // maybe?
        HideCaret(hUserInfoWnd);
    return lRes;
}
```

Comment: In my code I'm calling `HideCaret` every time a message gets sent to the window (outside WM_SETFOCUS). What are the drawbacks there? Is it significantly heavier for the system to call the function **every time**?

Comment: Probably doesn't make any difference, it just seems unnecessary to call it every time. Whatever works though :)

Comment: Oh well, it didn't work anyway if it was inside the if clause