# How to remove beam from textbox in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: Example Photo]

[image: Properties Photo]

How do I remove this flashing beam from the textbox? I've tried all the options in the Properties tab and I can't seem to disable it.

Comment: Have you considered using a label instead?

Comment: @Ian I guess, but I want the output box to be visible. Is there a way to do so using a label?

Comment: Don't think so.  What about setting the textbox to read-only?

Comment: The "beam" is a text cursor.  You may want to turn it off.  It shows where text should be typed.

Comment: @Ian I edited my post and added a Properties Photo. You can see my properties there. The textbox is currently set to read-only, but it's still showing up.

Comment: The cursor is there because the control has the focus.  How about setting the focus to another control, maybe when the form is displayed?

Comment: There is this way, if it's Managed C++: [C-cli textbox hidecaret hide blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803394/c-cli-textbox-hidecaret-hide-blinking-cursor)

Comment: and if it's not, there's this:  [C Win32 hide disable caret from an edit box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849201/c-win32-hide-disable-caret-from-an-edit-box)

Comment: That *beam* is called a *text caret*. It tells the user where the edit focus is located. If you don't want the text to be editable, don't use a textbox - a textbox is a single line **edit control**, which means it's used for editing text. If you want to display something that is not able to be edited, use a label, which is specifically designed for that purpose. A textbox tells the user 'use this to edit or add text*. Don't hand out a hammer when the proper tool for the job is a pair of pliers. IOW, use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @KenWhite, do you have any other suggestions on what could give the same look (output text area with a boundary), however, doesn't display the text caret?

Comment: Even if you can't edit the text (read-only edit box), you still need the caret for *selecting* text. That's why it's so hard to get rid of. A control to display text without selecting it is a `STATIC` control.

Comment: P.S. the easiest way to eliminate the caret is to put focus on a different control. You can control this with the tab order of the window.